# How to declare variables and use statements in LINQPad?

Tags: linqpad

Do you know how to declare variables in LINQPad in order to hold the query result and use it later in multiply queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just select C# or VB Statements, and you will be able to write variable declarations.

To view the content of your variables, you can use the Dump extension method available on all types:

```
var test = "Test String";
test.Dump(); // the content is shown in the output
```

Or you can use the `Console.Write` method.

[image: linqpad]

If you want to include method or class declarations within a LinqPad file, select C# or VB Program.